# Setting Color for mutliple buttons with one statement JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am very new to JavaFx. I can't find a way to condense this code. I'm not using fxml or scenebuilder.

Is there way to set color for multiple objects at one time?
or a way to create multiple objects at one time?

```
        Button b1 = new Button("BA1");
        Button b2 = new Button("BA2");
        Button b3 = new Button("BA3");
        Button b4 = new Button("BA4");
        Button b5 = new Button("BA5");
        Button b6 = new Button("BB6");
        Button b7 = new Button("BB7");
        Button b8 = new Button("BB8");
        Button b9 = new Button("BB9");
        Button b10 = new Button("BB10");
        Button b11 = new Button("BC11");
        Button b12 = new Button("BC12");
        Button b13 = new Button("BC13");
        Button b14 = new Button("BC14");
        Button b15 = new Button("BC15");

        b1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b4.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b5.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b6.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b7.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b8.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b9.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b10.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b11.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b12.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b13.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b14.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        b15.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a `for` loop, I don't think there's anything in JavaFX to do this. Using a `for` loop:

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
    Button b = new Button("BA" + i);
    b.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
    buttons.add(b);
}
```

Comment: Would the List be from the util or awt class?

Comment: Nothing should be `awt` unless it's 100% necessary. `util`